# Convert a 3D array to RGB valued array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

i have a 3D array like

```
[[[110403 676632 105064]
  [149110 204334 829800]
  [  1806    754   9555]]

 [[704375  27060 189080]
  [168544  93786 254782]
  [ 37446  23754 206955]]

 [[466900  34404 163800]
  [125518  84350 234913]
  [148988 841662 535410]]]
```

I want the entire array to be converted into value related to 0-255 **instead of clipping the values directly to 255**. For example if i have a number 7014 i want it in a range between 0-255.

i tried so many variants but none worked.Like

```
cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

&

```
np.dot(result, [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
```

How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: " i want it in a range between 0-255" is not specific enough. Assigning everything to `3` fits your requirement.

Comment: If there is a value x beyond 255. i want it to be converted to a number with in the range of (0 - 255)

Comment: 3 is in the range (0 - 255). So assign to 3.

Comment: Whats the logic here ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not so clear what you're asking, but here are some options to get you started:

## Manual Min-max transform

You could min-max transform so they are all in the range of `[0,1]`, and then multiply by 255. Then, all your values are in the range of 0 to 255, proportional to your original array (*i.e.* your minimum value will be 0 and your maximum value will be 255).

```
(arr-np.min(arr))/(np.max(arr)-np.min(arr))*255
```

This would give you:

```
array([[[ 33.25036151, 204.95570265,  31.63134374],
        [ 44.98801296,  61.73433955, 251.40292398],
        [  0.31901231,   0.        ,   2.66884725]],

       [[213.36859086,   7.97712711,  57.10866111],
        [ 50.88124979,  28.211362  ,  77.03237453],
        [ 11.12661552,   6.97460364,  62.52914112]],

       [[141.35580825,  10.20414837,  49.44266198],
        [ 37.83388908,  25.34995505,  71.00722671],
        [ 44.95101723, 255.        , 162.13102979]]])
```

## cv2 options:

As you tagged this `opencv`, you could also use their [`normalize` function](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#normalize):

```
import cv2

cv2.normalize(arr,0,255)
```

Also gives you an array between 0 and 255:

```
array([[[ 16,  96,  15],
        [ 21,  29, 117],
        [  0,   0,   1]],

       [[100,   4,  27],
        [ 24,  13,  36],
        [  5,   3,  29]],

       [[ 66,   5,  23],
        [ 18,  12,  33],
        [ 21, 119,  76]]], dtype=int32)
```

**Note**: you can get a min-max transform, as I showed manually above, using `cv2` as well:

```
cv2.normalize(arr,0,255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=5)

array([[[ 33.250362 , 204.9557   ,  31.631344 ],
        [ 44.988014 ,  61.73434  , 251.40292  ],
        [  0.3190123,   0.       ,   2.6688473]],

       [[213.36859  ,   7.977127 ,  57.10866  ],
        [ 50.88125  ,  28.211363 ,  77.03237  ],
        [ 11.126616 ,   6.9746037,  62.52914  ]],

       [[141.3558   ,  10.204148 ,  49.44266  ],
        [ 37.83389  ,  25.349955 ,  71.007225 ],
        [ 44.951015 , 255.       , 162.13103  ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: cv2.normalize did the job. What i needed was i didn't want to convert the value x greater than 255 directly to 255 or some other value. I wanted a function to normalize the values to a given range. I might have explained it in a bad way, sorry for that.

Comment: Glad it helped! In the future, being as specific as possible would help when you ask a question, and if possible, providing some sort of desired output. If your problem is solved, please consider accepting this answer :)

Comment: Yeah I did Mark it as answer. My rep is below 16 I think so it's not marking as answer. Sorry

Comment: Oh i didn't know this. Many thanks